# Construct a symmetric Poisson matrix from $\nabla \cdot (\rho\nabla p)$

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences, poissons-equation

Let $\rho$ and $p$ be 2D scalar fields. How do I construct a symmetric Matrix $A$ so that is satisfies

\begin{equation}
Ap = \nabla \cdot (\rho\nabla p)
\end{equation}

in finite differences? I am using a staggered grid, where $p$ is stored in the center of the cells, and $\rho$ is stored in both the center and the edges.

EDIT1:

So I tried the method suggested by User7530, and what I get are these coefficients:

$p_{i,j}$: $-\frac{4\rho_{i,j}}{h^2}$

$p_{i+1,j}$: $\frac{\rho_{i,j}}{h^2} + \frac{\rho_{i+1/2,j} - \rho_{i-1/2,j}}{2h^2}$

$p_{i-1,j}$: $\frac{\rho_{i,j}}{h^2} - \frac{\rho_{i+1/2,j} - \rho_{i-1/2,j}}{2h^2}$

$p_{i,j+1}$: $\frac{\rho_{i,j}}{h^2} + \frac{\rho_{i,j+1/2} - \rho_{i,j-1/2}}{2h^2}$

$p_{i,j-1}$: $\frac{\rho_{i,j}}{h^2} - \frac{\rho_{i,j+1/2} - \rho_{i,j-1/2}}{2h^2}$

The problem now is that, since I want the matrix to be symmetric, shouldn't the coefficient for $p_{i+1,j}$ be the same as for $p_{i-1,j}$?

Comment: On a structured grid? Unstructured grid? Are $p$ and $\rho$ discretized on the grid nodes? Edges?

Comment: A 'standard' second order symmetric discretisation is (here for $1$D) 

$$\left[\nabla\cdot(\rho \nabla p)\right]_{i} = \frac{\rho_{i+1/2}(p_{i+1}-p_i) - \rho_{i-1/2}(p_{i}-p_{i-1})}{h^2}$$ where $\rho_{i\pm 1/2} \equiv \frac{1}{2}(\rho_{i} + \rho_{i\pm 1})$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not one single way of discretizing this equation with finite differences; most approaches however will begin by applying the product rule to get

$$\nabla \cdot (\rho \nabla p) = \nabla \rho \cdot \nabla p + \rho \Delta p.$$

On a regular grid, now you can discretize the first term using e.g. central differences and the second term using e.g. the five-point stencil.

EDIT: If you have $\rho$ on the edges then you can get a symmetric expression by directly discretizing the original expression, as suggested by Winther:

$$\frac{\rho_{i+1/2,j}(p_{i+1,j} - p_{i,j}) + \rho_{i,j+1/2}(p_{i,j+1}-p_{i,j}) + \rho_{i-1/2,j}(p_{i-1,j}-p_{i,j})+\rho_{i,j-1/2}(p_{i,j-1/2}-p_{i,j})}{h^2}$$

Note that this expression agrees with the one you would get by finite volumes (draw a "dual" cell centered at $p_{i,j}$ and use Stokes's Theorem).

Comment: Okay so I have tried this, and as the result is quite long, I'll just update the question under EDIT1. I also updated the question regarding how I store the values.

Comment: @JohanBerglund Yes if you have edge quantities for $\rho$ you can use them as weights in the Laplacian stencil to get a symmetric discretization.

Comment: Ah yes, this is perfect, thank you!